# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'lat' cannot be nul

Tags: mysql, laravel

Am trying to save the lattitude and longitude of restaurant which is gained through admin input from a form

```
<div class="form-group">
                        {{Form::label('lat','Latitude')}}
                        {{Form::text('lat',null,['id'=>'lat','placeholder'=>'Insert here','name'=>'lat'])}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        {{Form::label('long','Longitude')}}
                        {{Form::text('long',null,['id'=>'lat','placeholder'=>'Insert here','name'=>'long'])}}
                </div>
```

This is the restaurant's controller

```
    $restaurant=new Restaurant;
    $restaurant->name= $request->input('name');
    $restaurant->menu=$request->input('menu');
    $restaurant->hours=$request->input('hours');
    $restaurant->contact=$request->input('contact');
    $restaurant->payment=$request->input('payment');
    $restaurant->description=$request->input('description');
    $restaurant->lat=$request->input('lat');
    $restaurant->long=$request->input('long');
    $restaurant->cover_image=$fileNameToStore;
    $restaurant->menu_image=$menuNameToStore;
    $restaurant->save();
```

Comment: Should the `name` be "description" on the form?

Dump the `input` params and check what they are, guessing lat and long are null/not-set while description have the value of the `long` param.

Comment: made the necessary changes but still same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got several issues that may be causing this error.  Your form has the same `id` for both lat and long (`lat`).  Your `name` for the fields is also repeated (`description`), and the same for both fields, as well as being different from the name assigned from the LaravelCollective `text()` form method, which is going to cause confusion.

With these issues, you may also be running into an automatically provided null value, based on Laravel's middleware converting empty strings to null. `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` is the default, and may be trying to decipher the multiple id/names and is possibly returning null based on the conflict.  This is located in **Kernal.php** if you are unfamiliar with the middleware.

If your database is not set up to allow null values on 'lat', this would give you the error, based on the above.

To fix, start small and just try with the simple, correct form elements.  **Note the extra null** in the `lat` form item - this is the correct # of elements for the Collective text method:

```
{{Form::text('lat', null, ['id'=>'lat','placeholder'=>'Insert here'])}}
```

and

```
{{Form::text('long',null,['id'=>'long','placeholder'=>'Insert here'])}}
```